# does odata do its filtering on the database or on my iis host?

Tags: asp.net, odata

if I implement the following api toystore.com/api/toys?$select=prodId&$filter=startswith(CompanyId,'lego') in ASP.NET, MVC, using odata3 and EF. Does that query get evaluated on my database (which is indexed and good at filtering) or do I retrieve all 100k rows and then filter them on my IIS webserver in memory? If it's the latter is there a way to make this more performant. thanks

edit - clarifying...
"can" asp.net odata queries ever filter on the database or are they *always* evaluated on the IIS?

related: [Enable lazy loading on OData URL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597019/enable-lazy-loading-on-odata-url-query)

Comment: I imagine this would depend on how it's all implemented, but in an ideal implementation it certainly *should* be filtering data at the database.  You can find out by profiling the database and observing the queries that get executed.

Comment: thanks, I've done my own profiling and in my implementation they get evaluated on the IIS. I don't know if that's an oData3 thing and if I ought to e.g. got to oData4

Answer (score 0):

If you return with IQueryable, where condition will be added in sql query. Thus, it will not pull all the data from the database. If you return an IEnumerable instead of IQueryable, it will pull all the data and filter it in iis.

I hope I have helped.